# Exponentiation with fractional power in a prime finite field

Tags: sage, exponentiation, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to do some exponentiation in the finite field modulo prime GF(8191) and I'm not sure why I don't get consistent results.

I compare those formulas: [image: k^((a-1)/a)] with [image: k*(1/k)^(1/a)] and [image: k*k^(-1/a)] which should return the same result (at least it does in [image: R])

The Sage code is really simple:

```
num, a = 42, 5000

# IN THE REAL DOMAIN:
k = float(num)^(a/(a-1))
print 'k=%f' % k
print 'real (A):', float(k^((a-1)/a)), float(k*((1/k)^(1/a)))
print 'real (B):', float(k^((a-1)/a)), float(k*(1/(k^(1/a))))
print 'real (C):', float(k^((a-1)/a)), float(k*(k^(-1/a)))
print

# NOW IN A FINITE FIELD:
order = 8191 # Field of prime size 2^13-1

# variable inv_a for convenience: 1/a and 1(a-1)
inv_a = inverse_mod(a, order)
inv_a1 = inverse_mod(a-1, order)

k = power_mod(num, a*inv_a1, order) # same "num" as in the Real domain
inv_k = inverse_mod(k, order)       # 1/k

print 'k=%d' % k
print 'finite (A):', power_mod(k, (a-1)*inv_a, order), k*power_mod(inv_k, inv_a, order) % order
print 'finite (C):', power_mod(k, (a-1)*inv_a, order), k*power_mod(k, -inv_a, order) % order
```

Which outputs:

```
k=42.031414
real (A): 42.0 42.0
real (B): 42.0 42.0
real (C): 42.0 42.0

k=416
finite (A): 5080 7898
finite (C): 5080 7898
```

In the finite field I was expecting the formulas to give the same result, just like in the commutative field of real numbers, but I get `5080` and `7898` instead of `42`.

If you know why, thanks to let me know. Especially if there's a problem with the code.

Answer (score 1):

Modular arithmetics does not apply to exponents, which are integer numbers rather than finite field elements. For example, in the field GF(3) we have 1 = 4, but 2<sup>1</sup> ≠ 2<sup>4</sup> (the latter element is 16, which is 1 mod 3). So your idea of obtaining k<sup>1/a</sup> by computing the reciprocal of a in the finite field and then raising k to that power is not going to work. Taking roots in finite field is hard (when they exist at all), which is useful in cryptography.

Sage has a built-in function for [taking roots in finite fields](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/finite_rings/sage/rings/finite_rings/element_base.html#sage.rings.finite_rings.element_base.FinitePolyExtElement.nth_root):

```
F = GF(8191)
num = F(51)
a = 5000
print num.nth_root(a)
```

prints 781.  Your example, 42, throws an error as it is not the 5000th power of any element in this field, and thus does not have a 5000th root.

Letting `r = num.nth_root(a)`, we can now compute num<sup>(a-1)/a</sup> either by raising r to power (a-1) or by dividing num by r; same thing.

```
print num/r, r^(a-1)
```

prints 2643 for both.

---

Roots are not unique in general. To get all of them, use

```
print num.nth_root(a, all=True)
```

which prints [781, 7997, 1936, 7364, 4453, 7410, 194, 6255, 827, 3738]